# Attach an unknown device to WSL2 with usbipd

Tags: usb, wsl2

I am trying to attach a USB device to WSL2, the device drivers are not present on Windows, and it appears as an unknown device in `Settings -> Bluetooth & Other Devices` and it appears as following from the PS utility.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_.InstanceID -match '^USB' }  
Status     Class           FriendlyName                        InstanceId
Error                                                          USB\VID_03FD...
```

And it does not appear at all when I do `usbipd wsl list`.

Is there a way to somehow attach it to WSL2 anyway?

- The device: Xilinx Platform Cable USB, used to program Xilinx FPGAs.
- Host OS: Windows 10 Home 19044
- WSL: CentOS Linux 8

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm going to have to say that this will be very difficult.  You'll need to get the Xilinx driver running in the WSL2 kernel, which will require you to build your own kernel and figure out the correct modules to include.  From some Google searches on installing the drivers into Linux, it appears that Xilinx only supports a small number of Linux distributions directly, and even on those people struggle to get it installed.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds the actual program called Vivado or ISE do install the necessary drivers, problem is that they need to see the device first. Given that I cannot attach the device to WSL, even if I were to build my own kernel, it wouldn't make much of a difference. Perhaps I was unclear, but I am not trying to install the drivers, although this is the final goal, all I need right now is to be able to pass the usb device to WSL, which normally would have been done with `usbipd` tool.

Comment: Apologies - I totally missed the line about it not appearing in `usbipd wsl list`.  That's actually odd - I would expect it to be there. :-/

Comment: This is a super interesting problem.  Your USB device is probably identifying itself as class FFh (vendor specific who-ha) and isn't getting passed through.  MOST devices identify is one of the know USB class types making it easy to pass through.  The known types don't actually use drivers beyond the default BT stack.  I have to wonder if this is a shortcoming of WSL2.  You might first identify if you are indeed using a class FFh device.. then look into how to connect THOSE to WSL of any brand to get closer.. just a thought.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Well, I can try that tomorrow and keep the post updated.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Is there any tool that can determine the device class? I have tried [usbview](https://ftdichip.com/utilities/) from FTDI, and it too failed to see the device. I cannot seem to find any built-in utilities for PS or applications as such.

Comment: You can go into the device manager.. find it.. right click -> properties -> details -> Property Dropdown.  "Compatible Ids" (and other items on the dropdown).   Look at the Class_xx entries.  [Here](https://www.usb.org/defined-class-codes) is a simple list of the device classes.  I don't have any 0xFF devices here so I can't see what that might look like.